# Magento 2 Check If Customer is Subscribed to Newsletter

Tags: magento2, module, customer, magento-2.1, newsletter

I am developing this custom xml export/import. In magento 2 how can I check if a customer is subscribed to newsletter? Right now I am loading the customer factory.

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
```

But this does not give information about newsletter is there another model I have to load?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First inject the `\Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber` class in your constructor:

```
protected $_subscriber;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber $subscriber
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->_subscriber= $subscriber;
    ...
}
```

Then you have two possible cases

### Assuming your have the customer email

Then in your code you can call the following code to check whether or not the customer is subscribed to the newsletter:

```
$checkSubscriber = $this->_subscriber->loadByEmail($customerEmail);

if ($checkSubscriber->isSubscribed()) {
    // Customer is subscribed
} else {
    // Customer is not subscribed
}
```

### Assuming you have the customer id

You can call the following code:

```
$checkSubscriber = $this->_subscriber->loadByCustomerId($customerId);

if ($checkSubscriber->isSubscribed()) {
    // Customer is subscribed
} else {
    // Customer is not subscribed
}
```

Comment: where would you execute this code?