# Checking if user is newsletter subscriber or not

Tags: magento2, newsletter, newsletter-subscriber

I want to check that the user is newsletter subscriber or not in email footer template in admin panel. I am unable to find a variable which can check like this:

```
{{ if($userIsSubscriber) { //Code//}}}
```

I know above syntax is wrong but I need code somewhat like this as I want to show some specific part of template to our user who are subscribers.

Thanks

Comment: Where you want to check this condition in template or block?

Comment: I wan to check it in my footer template of email (In Marketing->Email Templates->footer template of my current theme)

Comment: In Magento 2 Backend

Comment: like {{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}} I want to use {{var subscriber.isSubscribed()}}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory`
class in your constructor by injecting it like this:

```
protected $subscriberFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
){
    $this->subscriberFactory= $subscriberFactory;
}
```

Then in your execute function you can check customer if subscribe or not to the newsletter.

```
public function execute()
{
   $customerId = 1;
   $userIsSubscriber = $this->subscriberFactory->loadByCustomerId($customerId);

   if ($userIsSubscriber->isSubscribed()) {
       // return Customer is subscribed
   } else {
       // return Customer is not subscribed
   }
}
```

Comment: This link will help: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134201/magento-2-check-if-customer-is-subscribed-to-newsletter

Comment: but How I will I get this in edit->template

if ($userIsSubscriber->isSubscribed()) {

Comment: I want to use this variable in backend

Comment: like {{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}} I want to use {{var subscriber.isSubscribed()}}